# Experimental Validation of Schrodinger's Electron Cloud theory

Tags: experimental-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms, electrons, electronic-configuration

I am currently doing a report for school on the electron cloud atomic structure theory. One of the major points on my report is the experiments performed by the scientists (Schrodinger and Heisenberg) to validate their hypothesis.

I cannot find any evidence of any experiments performed by them to validate their claim. Did they perform any experiments or was their theory purely based on mathematics? (There seems to be a lot of that surrounding this topic)

Thanks in advance, Sam.

Comment: Schrodinger & Heisenberg were theoreticians, they didn't do experiments, but a lot of experimental data were obtained already by experimentalists that required new theory. There are myriads sources on that matter. And of course, myriads experiments were done after the invention of quantum mechanics as well to test it validity.

Comment: Sorry to have to ask but could you link some of the sources please? Thanks